# Eclipse PDE headless build fails with: failed to create task or type eclipse.generateFeature

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

I want to build an Eclipse RCP application with a [PDE headless build](http://www.eclipse.org/pde/pde-build/). When I run the Ant script of the build it fails with the following error message:

```
failed to create task or type eclipse.generateFeature 
Cause: The name is undefined.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution in the discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vogella/OXp6TGD4VTY): 
It is important to run the Ant script of the build within the same JRE as the workspace because otherwise the PDE Ant tasks cannot be found:

Right click on the Ant script (build.xml) > Run As > Ant Build … > JRE tab of the wizard > switch to option: 'Run in the same JRE as the workspace'

Comment: If running from the command line instead of from inside the Eclipse IDE, then you would run the build using "eclipse -application
org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner -buildfile <file>" rather than just running ant directly.